# How to Autowired a service in JobExecutionListener?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a JobExecutionListener named jobLoggerListener that config in my spring batch job and Override two methods(Afer Job and Before Job). I want to update a table when a job started in beforeJob Method and again update it when job finished.In order to do that, I implement a service that annotated by @Service that call repository to do updating process. But When I used @AutoWired in my jobLoggerListenner class to Inject my service, I got "Null Pointer Exception". How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're really going to need to post your configuration artifacts if you want an answer.

Comment: Make sure the `JobExecutionListener` in which you are trying to autowire the service is declared a bean so that dependency injection works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used .listener(new JobLoggerListener()) in my batch config file, so, in order to fix the issue, I changed the simple class to spring component then autowired it to the config file.

Answer (score 1):

You get it because spring doesn't know about your class or doesn't do `@Autowired`. Show some code and errors list. 
P.S. How did you exacly write `@AutoWired`? With 2 Uppercase letter? There is no annotation @AutoWired. Use `@Autowired` instead and do not forget to do import.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
```